# How do I apply a class to a form label via theme?

Tags: 8, forms

I have created a form with a label and input fields. I have an abc.theme file.

I tried using the following code.

```
function abc_preprocess_label(&$variables) {
   $element = $variables['element'];
   $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'test';
}
```

How do I apply a class to the form label?

But seems not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook to preprocess is form_element_label. This is a working version:

```
function abc_preprocess_form_element_label(&$variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes->addClass('class_name');
}
```